# Find the points at which the diameter intersects the circumference of the circle.

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I am working on an optic simulation program. I reached a stage where I am unable to find an algorithm for the desired points.
Here is the required problem,
[image]

I figured out how to find the equation of line AA'. 2f is the center of the arc. I have the values of radius of the arc and coordinates of its center.

### Question:

Given the equation of line AA', radius of the circle, and coordinates of center,
Find the points at which AA' (diameter) intersects the circle? I need the second solution also for the convex mirror simulation.

Comment: If the circle has radius $r$ and centre $(a,b)$ then it has equation $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ and the line has the form $y = mx+c$. Substitute for $y$ from line into circle and solve the corresponding quadratic for $x$